# Expected linebreaks to be 'LF' but found 'CRLF' but in only one file

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, eslint, prettier, eslint-config-airbnb

I am getting is eslint error in one of my files `Expected linebreaks to be 'LF' but found 'CRLF'`

I am on a Mac and all the other files dont give this error. All files should be the same as i have edit on save turned on and it formats all files the same way. Why this particular file gives me this error?

Here's my settings, did i do something wrong here?

eslintrc below

```
{
  "extends": [
    "eslint-config-airbnb",
    "plugin:flowtype/recommended"
  ],
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "node": true,
    "mocha": true,
  },
  "parser": "babel-eslint",
  "rules": {
    "no-nested-ternary": 0,
    "import/no-unresolved": 0,
    "import/no-named-as-default": 0,
    "no-unused-expressions": 0,
    "comma-dangle": 0, // not sure why airbnb turned this on. gross!
    "indent": [2, 2, {
      "SwitchCase": 1
    }],
    "no-console": 0,
    "no-alert": 0,
    "id-length": 0,
    "no-script-url": 0,
    "import/no-extraneous-dependencies": 0,
    "no-underscore-dangle": 0,
    "react/jsx-filename-extension": 0,
    "global-require": 0,
    "import/newline-after-import": 0,
    "import/extensions": 0,
    "prefer-template": 0,
    "max-len": 0,
    "react/prefer-stateless-function": 0,
    "react/forbid-prop-types": 0,
    "jsx-a11y/href-no-hash": "off",
    "function-paren-newline": 0,
    "react/no-typos": 0,
    "jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid": 0,
    "react/default-props-match-prop-types": 0,
    "arrow-parens": 0,
    "jsx-a11y/label-has-for": [2, {
      "required": {
        "every": ["id"]
      },
    }],
  },
  "plugins": [
    "react",
    "import",
    "flowtype"
  ],
  "settings": {
    "import/parser": "babel-eslint",
    "import/resolve": {
      "moduleDirectory": ["node_modules", "src"]
    }
  },
  "globals": {
    "__CLIENT__": true,
    "__SERVER__": true,
    "beforeAll": true,
    "afterAll": true,
  }
}
```

prettierrc

```
{
  "printWidth": 100,
  "trailingComma": "all",
  "tabWidth": 2,
  "semi": true,
  "singleQuote": true
}
```

.editorconfig

```
# http://editorconfig.org
root = true
[*]
charset = utf-8
end_of_line = lf
indent_size = 2
indent_style = space
insert_final_newline = true
max_line_length = 100
trim_trailing_whitespace = true
[*.md]
max_line_length = 0
trim_trailing_whitespace = false
[{Makefile,**.mk}]
# Use tabs for indentation (Makefiles require tabs)
indent_style = tab
[*.scss]
indent_size = 2
indent_style = space
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Was that file created on a different machine?

Personally I would just run eslint with `—fix` flag and not worry about it.